# Proving this set is compact in $L^2(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

> Let $\Omega = [0,1]^d \subset \mathbb{R}^d, d \ge 3$, and for any $x
>  \in \Omega$ define $$Tf(x) \equiv \int_{\Omega} e^{-
>  \frac{(y-x)^2}{2}}f(y) \lambda (dy) $$ for any $f : \Omega \to
>  \mathbb{R}$ for which the RHS is well defined. Using Sobolev
> inequality or otherwise, show that the following set $$ \{Tf :
>  \|f\|_{L^2} \le 2 \}$$ is compact in $L^2(\Omega)$.

**My questions:**

1. Is my attempt below correct?
2. How would we even use the Sobolev inequality here? I thought that the only thing we need is the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem.
3. Is there an easy way to see the above set is closed?

**My attempt:**

I proved that $Tf \in L^2(\Omega)$ and also $\|Tf\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \le C$ for every $f$ in the set above, but now I need to find the weak derivative $\partial_{x_i} Tf$ and show it is in $L^2(\Omega)$ as well. But I am not sure how to find $\partial_{x_i} Tf$. My attempt with this:

Since our function is smooth then the weak derivative is equal to the ordinary partial derivative. So we calculate:

$$\partial_{x_i} Tf = \int_{\Omega} \partial_{x_i}e^{- \frac{(y-x)^2}{2}}f(y) \lambda (dy) = \int_{\Omega} (y-x)e^{- \frac{(y-x)^2}{2}}f(y) \lambda (dy)$$
And now:
$$|\partial_{x_i} Tf(x)| \le \int_{\Omega} |2| \cdot 1 \cdot |f(y)|  \lambda (dy) \le 2 \cdot \|f\|_2 $$ so
$$\|\partial_{x_i} Tf\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \le 2\lambda(\Omega)^{\frac{1}{2}} \|f\|_2 \le 4\lambda(\Omega)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$ Hence any weak derivative of first order is in $L^2(\Omega)$ and in fact since the above bound works for any $f$ with $\|f\|_2 \le 2$ then we have that our set is bounded in $H^{1}(\Omega)$. By Rellich-Kondrachov theorem this set is precompact in $L^2(\Omega)$ but since it is closed (I am not sure how to prove this actually) then it is compact in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need Rellich-Kondrachov's theorem. You only need Ascoli-Arzelà theorem. As you write in your attempt:
$$\partial_{x_i} Tf (x) = \int_{\Omega} \partial_{x_i}e^{- \frac{(y-x)^2}{2}}f(y) \lambda (dy) = \int_{\Omega} (y-x)e^{- \frac{(y-x)^2}{2}}f(y) \lambda (dy)$$
and thus for all $i \in \{1,\dots,d\}$ and for all $x \in \Omega$ we have that:
$$|\partial_{x_i} Tf(x)| \le \int_{\Omega} |2| \cdot 1 \cdot |f(y)|  \lambda (dy) \le 2 \cdot \|f\|_2$$
end then $\|\nabla Tf\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \leq 2q \|f\|_2 \leq 4d$ for all $f$ such that $\|f\|_2 \leq 2$.
The family $\{Tf : \|f\|_{L^2} \le 2 \}$ is uniformly $4d$-Lipschitz continuous. What follows from Ascoli-Arzelà's theorem is that $\{Tf : \|f\|_{L^2} \le 2 \}$ is relatively compact. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a much nicer solution. But is my attempt also correct? If so what would be the easiest way to see the set in question is closed? I was thinking of writing it as the preimage of an open set under a continuous function but I was having trouble constructing such a function.